# Why view is not refreshed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

Ruby 2.5.1p57 Rails 5.2.3

Basically I have Controller and in it I have method 'search' which I am calling from form

```rb
def search
    Warehouse.where("product = '#{params[:product]}'").find_each do |warehouse|
      Area.where("warehouse_id = #{warehouse.id} and post_codes like '%#{params[:postcode]}%'").find_each do |area|
        PriceList.where("area_id = #{area.id} and number_of_pallets = #{params[:number_of_palette]}").find_each do |priceList|
          puts "Warehouse  #{warehouse} Area: #{area} PriceList #{priceList}"
          render_pricing warehouse
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def render_pricing(warehouse)
    p warehouse # everything is here, I can see data which I want
    @warehouse = warehouse
    render 'search'
  end
```

and almost everything works like I wanted except that 'render' does not render 'search' I am getting no errors, nothing. I have 'search' like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Price Lists</title>
</head>
<body>
<%= tag.h1 do %>
  Wyszukaj magazyn
<% end %>

<%= form_with(url: warehouse_search_path, method: "get",  :id => "search")  do %>
    <%= tag.div class: "form_tag_container" do %>
        <%= label :product, "Produkt" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :product %>
    <% end %>
    <%= tag.div class: "form_tag_container" do %>
      <%= label :postcode, "Kod pocztowy" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :postcode %>
    <% end %>
    <%= tag.div class: "form_tag_container" do %>
      <%= label :number_of_palette, "Ilosc palet" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :number_of_palette %>
    <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<h1>Price List</h1>
<%= link_to "Dodaj magazyn", price_list_add_warehouse_path %>
<br>
<br>
<%= "WSAD: #{@warehouse}" %>
<table id="warehouses">
  <tr><th>Warehouse</th><th>Product</th><th>Cena brutto</th><th>Cena brutto 1 tona</th><th>Transport dla klienta</th></tr>
  <%# @warehouses.each do |warehouse| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @warehouse.warehouse_name %></td>
      <td><%= @warehouse.product %></td>
      <td><%= @warehouse.warehouse_detail.gross_price %></td>
      <td><%= @warehouse.warehouse_detail.price_pellete_per_tone %></td>
      <td><%= @warehouse.warehouse_detail.order_price %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edytuj", root_path %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Usun", warehouse_destroy_path(@warehouse.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
    </tr>
  <%# end %>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that the url does not get change and my 'search' html does not get load with new data I am not sure what I am doing wrong, cause I have 5 others similar methods which working correctly, but that one I can not fix.

Comment: Perhaps try `return render_pricing warehouse`?

Comment: Perhaps try to write a path instead of just 'search'?

Comment: @NicolásNisoria that does not help

Comment: Did you try with redirect_to instead of render?

Comment: @NicolásNisoria yes, I tried that but with no good results

Comment: How about to user separate action for `search`?

Comment: @kunashir not sure what you mean, I have separate using separate method for `search` and separate for rendering, more explanation please

Comment: I've meant try to use separate action to render the form like `search_form` and separate action for `search`. Thus you will have two different URL but they will use a single template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in the `remote: true` which `form_with` adds by default.

```
<%= form_with(url: warehouse_search_path, method: "get",  :id => "search", local: true)  do %>
```

Must fix your problem.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Comment: dude, I love you <3 I was struggling with that issue two day and no google link does provide me that answer :)